# how to show milliseconds in points in vis timeline in js

Tags: reactjs, vis-timeline

Is there anyway that we can show milliseconds of vis timeline in points for ex: 0.2 instead to 200 and 0.00 istead of 000[image]

Answer (score 0):

The format of the time axis can be controlled with the `format` configuration option, this is described [in this section of the documnetation](https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/docs/timeline/#Configuration_Options). Full details on the supported formatting syntax can be found in the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) documentation. If the syntax you'd like isn't supported you can write your own function to complete the formatting.

From your description I believe you'd like to display in the format `<second>.<fractional seconds>`. This would be achieved with the millisecond format `s.SSS`.

An example options object for vis-timeline with this option set:

```
var options = {
  format: {
    minorLabels: {
      millisecond: 's.SSS',
    }
  }
};
```

Code snippet with this option set:

```js
// DOM element where the Timeline will be attached
var container = document.getElementById("visualization");

// Create a DataSet (allows two way data-binding)
var items = new vis.DataSet([
  {id: 1, content: "item 1", start: "2022-07-20 13:52:10.001"},
  {id: 2, content: "item 2", start: "2022-07-20 13:52:10.250"},
  {id: 3, content: "item 3", start: "2022-07-20 13:52:11.100"},
  {id: 4, content: "item 4", start: "2022-07-20 13:52:10.000", end: "2022-07-20 13:52:10.900"},
  {id: 5, content: "item 5", start: "2022-07-20 13:52:10.800"},
  {id: 6, content: "item 6", start: "2022-07-20 13:52:10.990", type: "point"},
  {id: 7, content: "item 7", start: "2022-07-20 13:52:10.000", end: "2022-07-20 13:52:11.200"},
]);

// Configuration for the Timeline
var options = {
  format: {
    minorLabels: {
      millisecond: 's.SSS',
    }
  }
};

// Create a Timeline
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
```

```css
body,
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/standalone/umd/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/styles/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="visualization"></div>
```